# Probability that sample mean of poisson is closer to lambda than sample variance

Tags: poisson-distribution, estimators

Let's say you have a random variable $X$ which follows Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Now, if you have a sample of size $n$, you could estimate $\lambda$ with either the sample mean $\bar{x_n}$ or sample variance $S^2_n$. Although they are both unbiased estimators of $\lambda$, $\bar{x_n}$ is more efficient.

So given a sample, what is the probability that $\bar{x_n}$ is closer to $\lambda$ than $S^2_n$ i.e. $\mathbb{P}(|\bar{x_n} - \lambda|<|S^2_n - \lambda|)$?

Comment: Just to note, a comparison of efficiency is a comparison between variances.  The variance of the sample variance is larger than the sample mean for Poisson data.  Since both are unbiased, the sample mean is more efficient.

Comment: I think the point I'm trying to make there is that $\bar{x_n}$ has lower mse than  $S^2_n$ when estimating $\lambda$ but what does that mean for the odds of $\bar{x_n}$ being closer to $\lambda$ than $S^2_n$?

Comment: Yes I understand the question.  I will say that this is a very difficult question to answer in closed-form.  Perhaps simulation is all one can rely on